# how to write regex that matches any one of multiple patterns?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Is it possible to construct a regex for a set of strings that will match either pattern 1 or pattern 2 where both patterns have the same number of capture groups ?

I need to retrieve string segments by indexing into the array of capture groups independent of knowing whether the string matched pattern 1 or 2.

```
pattern 1 
I545XY
([I])(\d{3})()([A-Z]{2})

pattern 2 
O5480000031000ZZ
([O])(\d{3})(\d{10})([A-Z]{2})
```

So each pattern has 4 groups. Groups 1,2,4 are identical. Group 3 is missing from pattern 1.

I want to index any result ( whether pattern 1 or 2 ) across full-range of group indexes (1,2,3,4).

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you wish to design this expression:

```
^([IO])(\d{3})(\d{10})?([A-Z]{2})$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hgfjD5/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/hgfjD5/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this regex, all the groups are present and eventually empty:

```
^([IO])(\d{3})((?:\d{10})?)([A-Z]{2})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWcOF0/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex needs to match both of the given patterns.
The provided answers combine both patterns into one.
But they miss to check if any of the patterns is actually correct.

So i added the lookahead:

```
(?=I\d{3}[A-Z]{2}|O\d{3}\d{10}[A-Z]{2})([IO])(\d{3})((?:\d{10})?)([A-Z]{2})
```

This asserts that any of the two pattern matches and **then** matches the combined version.

Without the lookahead the regex would match

```
I5480000031000ZZ
```

Note the part `((?:\d{10})?)`, this whill ensure that the 3rd capture group will be matched, even if its empty.

Comment: what is the purpose of the positive lookahead ? seems to work fine without it

Comment: @BaltoStar I edited the answer and provided an example